# Confusion for return statements when using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am using recursion to insert a node at the end of the linked list. The code works fine. But I am a little confused with the return statements.

Going through one by one of my understanding:

The first return will return a new node `head == null` and the function will finish - nothing more to do

The second will return a node that was created at the end of the tail - nothing more to do

The last will put all the nodes on the stack everytime insertNodeAtTail is called recursively. When the second return is called `head.next == null`. All the nodes will be popped off the stack until it gets to the first one. Effectively being the first node in the linked list (pointing to head).

Is my understanding correct?

```
public Node insertNodeAtTail(Node head, int data) {
    if(head == null) {
    /* List is empty so just return the new node */
        Node node = new Node();
        node.data = data;
        node.next = null;
        return node;
    }
    else if (head.next == null) {
    /* We are at the end of the list so insert the new node */
        Node node = new Node();
        node.data = data;
        head.next = node;
        return head;
    }
    else {
    /* Travese the list by passing the next node in the list until next is NULL */
        insertNodeAtTail(head.next, data);
    }

    /* This will put all the head nodes on the stack and then pop them off at the end */ 
    return head;
 }
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. I'm not sure what the point of the return value is, it isn't being used.

Comment: @Zar it probably exists to retrieve the root node each time something is added, since the root node will always be returned.

Comment: Note the the first case (`head == null`) doesn't add anything to the List (that is, unless you assign the Node returned by your method to the `head` member of your List - if you don't do that, your method doesn't work for empty Lists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do this

```
public Node insertNodeAtTail(Node head, int data) {
 if(head == null) {
    head = new Node(data);
 }
 else{
    head.next = insertNodeAtTail(head.next,data);
 }
 return head;
}
```

Comment: I moved the return head inside the else statement and the code works ok. I know it works. But still confused with the head.next = insertNodeAtTail(head.next, data); What will that insertNodeAtTail return?

Comment: It will add a node in the end of the list and return the head in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You simply put return in wrong place, having returned same head element.

```
else {
/* Travese the list by passing the next node in the list until next is NULL */
    return insertNodeAtTail(head.next, data);
}
```

Im writing this from head please check.

Comment: Actually, I did try that and the function crashed with a null exception.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your understanding is correct... :)

Answer (score 1):

Last return will cause problems as it will cause Head to always point to second last node of your list. You should remove that as suggested by FallAndLearn. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The original code I wrote in my question did succeed in my test cases so it will always return the first head at the beginning as all the nodes will be popped of the stack and the last one to be popped of the stack will be the first one. So head will be point to the first node.